# I change my admin URL to a custom URL and I cannot access my store admin anymore.

Tags: url, magento2.2.6

I change my admin URL to a custom URL and I cannot access my store admin anymore.

How can I revert the change that I made?

Comment: How did you change the admin URL, i.e. from **`admin panel`** or from the **`database`** or using **`app/etc/env.php`** file?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Go to your database and find the table `core_config_data`

Find the path column `web/unsecure/base_url` and `web/secure/base_url`

Then edit the value column of those rows. Remember to use `/` at the ending of the URLs or it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the other answers, if you do not want to modify the DB, you can use the CLI.

If you have changed the admin path, from the CLI run: `bin/magento config:set admin/url/use_custom_path 0`
This will make the admin path the one that you have in app/etc/env.php (it should be in the beginning of the file):

`'backend' => ['frontName' => 'admin']` (in this case, admin) be the admin path for your store.

If you want to have a custom admin path, you can leave `admin/url/use_custom_path` to have a value of 1, and you can run `bin/magento config:set admin/url/custom_path adminpaththatyouwant`, and in this case, you can access the admin panel at /adminpaththatyouwant.

If you have changed the admin URL, run: `bin/magento config:set admin/url/use_custom 0`

Don't forget to flush the cache after running these commands:

`bin/magento cache:flush`

Answer (score -1):

You need to run below query in database:

```
UPDATE core_config_data SET value = 0 WHERE path = 'admin/url/use_custom';
UPDATE core_config_data SET value = 'http://127.0.0.1/m2/admin/' WHERE path = 'admin/url/custom';
UPDATE core_config_data SET value = 'http://127.0.0.1/m2/' WHERE path = 'web/secure/base_url';
UPDATE core_config_data SET value = 'http://127.0.0.1/m2/' WHERE path = 'web/unsecure/base_url';
```

Remove `var` folder

**Note:** change you admin and front URL in query

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

In admin panel go to `Stores > Configuration`

In Configuration Go to `Advanced > Admin > Admin Base URL`. In this section you can change your admin URL. (Refer Below Screenshot)

[image]

After changing the URL don't forget to flush the Magento cache.

Comment: He can't access the admin (backend), how is he supposed to do this????